# Connecting R Shiny app to Dropbox not working

Tags: r, shiny, dropbox

This is literally driving me mad and I've been working on it for so long that I figured I'd post my issue on here. Any help is appreciated!

The problem: I created a basic Dropbox account. I have a Shiny application and would like to use a stored data file from Dropbox within the app. I followed the steps to create an application on Dropbox and set the app to require full access to my files. I then ran the code below in R:

```
drop_auth(new_user = TRUE,key = "key",secret = "secret",cache = TRUE)
```

where key and secret are the actual key and secret for my application. A web browser is opened in Chrome with the error below.

[image]

I have looked up solutions online, however, none of them provides a clear enough explanation for me to follow along (obviously I am lacking knowledge). Can someone pleeeease help me with this. Thanks!

Comment: Does the console output any warning/error? Would be good to understand what in your request throws the error.

Comment: Does this help perhaps? https://github.com/karthik/rdrop2/issues/42. One possible resolution listed here is to ensure the httpuv package is installed `install.packages("httpuv")`.

Comment: There is no error in the console. It only prints out "Enter authorization code..." which I have no idea where to find. Installing the "httpuv" library didn't help :(

Comment: @AyeTown The message in the screenshot you shared mentions "information below", but your screenshot doesn't show it. The page should have more specific error information at the bottom of the page. Can you share what it says?

Answer (score 2):

You haven't provided much code to work on here but I'm assuming you're using `rdrop2`? In your code above, you've provided several arguments to `drop_auth()` but, [as per the package's documentation](https://github.com/karthik/rdrop2), run `drop_auth()` with no arguments - this should open a browser window and allow you to authorise the connection:

```
library(rdrop2)
drop_auth()

### PINCHED FROM RDROP2 DOCUMENTATION ###

# This will launch your browser and request access to your Dropbox account. You will be prompted to log in if you aren't already logged in.
# Once completed, close your browser window and return to R to complete authentication. 
# The credentials are automatically cached (you can prevent this) for future use.

# If you wish to save the tokens, for local/remote use

token <- drop_auth()
saveRDS(token, file = "token.rds")

# Then in any drop_* function, pass `dtoken = token
# Tokens are valid until revoked.
```

If you have multiple Dropbox accounts, I recommend signing out of all of them prior to running the above code. When the browser window launches, it should then ask you to sign in to the account you need and complete the authentication process.